# The performance of openmp

Tags: c, windows, performance, openmp

i'm making test about the performance of openmp,bu i find some strange results,here are my test code:

```
void test()
{
int a = 0;
clock_t t1 = clock();
int length =50000;
double *t3 = new double[length]();
double *t4 = new double[length]();
for (int i = 0; i <8000; i++)
{
for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
    {
        t3[j] = t3[j] + t4[j];
    }
}
clock_t t2 = clock();
printf("Time = %d  %d\n", t2 - t1,omp_get_thread_num());
delete[] t3;
delete[] t4;
}

int main()
{
clock_t t1 = clock();
printf("In parallel region：\n");
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
{

    test(); 
}

clock_t t2 = clock();
printf("Total time = %d\n", t2 - t1);
printf("In sequential region：\n");
test();
printf("\n");
```

}

when i set the `length=50000` or `length=100000` or `length=150000` respectively,the results are showed in the figure:
[image]

it is strange that

- the elapsed time is not a straight line up (the elapsed time when `length=150000`is almost 5 times of that when `length=50000`), while the amount of calculation is a straight line up.
- it also strange that elapsed time for the test function in the parallel region doesn’t equal to the elapsed time for the test function in the sequential region when `length=150000`.

my cpu is intel Core i5-4590(4 cores) and platform is vs2013 ,win8

I’m eager to hope somebody can tell me the reason and how to solve this problem to improve the performance of openmp,thank you very much.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi i pick this code from a book ,so what timer should I use to get the correct result?

Comment: @Debo use `omp_get_wtime()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing strange here. Your code is [memory bound](http://crd.lbl.gov/departments/computer-science/PAR/research/roofline) and the slowdown when going from `length=50000` to longer arrays is due to the data no longer being able to fit into the CPU last-level cache.

- `length=50000`: data size is 4 threads x 2 arrays x 50000 elements x 8 bytes per element = 3.05 MiB < L3 cache size (6 MiB for [i5-4590](http://ark.intel.com/products/80815/Intel-Core-i5-4590-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_70-GHz))
- `length=100000`: data size is 6.10 MiB > L3 cache size
- `length=150000`: data size is 9.16 MiB > L3 cache size

In the second case, the array is just slightly larger than the CPU cache, therefore the time difference is only a bit bigger than 2x. In the third case, half of the array data cannot be fitted into the cache and must be streamed from and to the main memory.

When the function is called from the main thread only, the memory used is 1/4 of what is used in the parallel region and the arrays fit entirely in the L3 cache for all three different lengths.

Check my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36966474/multi-threading-performance-in-multiplication-of-2-arrays-images-intel-ipp) for more details.

Comment: Doesn't each CPU has it's own cache?

Comment: @RishitSanmukhani, i5-4590 has 6 MiB of shared L3 cache and each of the four cores has 256 KiB of private L2 cache and 32 KiB of private L1 cache.